# jQuery parse JSON multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, json, arrays

I have a JSON array like this:

```
{
  "forum":[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "created":"2010-03-19 ",
      "updated":"2010-03-19 ","user_id":"1",
      "vanity":"gamers",
      "displayname":"gamers",
      "private":"0",
      "description":"All things gaming",
      "count_followers":"62",
      "count_members":"0",
      "count_messages":"5",
      "count_badges":"0",
      "top_badges":"",
      "category_id":"5",
      "logo":"gamers.jpeg",
      "theme_id":"1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to use jQuery `.getJSON` to be able to return the values of each of the array values, but I'm not sure as to how to get access to them.

So far I have this jQuery code:

```
$.get('forums.php', function(json, textStatus) {
            //optional stuff to do after success
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(json);

        });
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: You've a large object inside an array (which actually contains only one item, the object). This is likely a confusion of terminology. It's unclear what you want to end up. Please elaborate. What would you like to end up? Displaying each object property as key=value pair? Reading this guide may help you a bit further as well to get terminology right: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29 (and maybe even answer your own question).

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned that the forum array has more then one sub array items

Comment: I see, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `{}` in JSON represents an object. Each of the object's properties is represented by `key:value` and comma separated. The property values are accessible by the key using the period operator like so `json.forum`. The `[]` in JSON represents an array. The array values can be any object and the values are comma separated. To iterate over an array, use a standard for loop with an index. To iterate over object's properties without referencing them directly by key you could use `for in` loop:

```
var json = {"forum":[{"id":"1","created":"2010-03-19 ","updated":"2010-03-19 ","user_id":"1","vanity":"gamers","displayname":"gamers","private":"0","description":"All things gaming","count_followers":"62","count_members":"0","count_messages":"5","count_badges":"0","top_badges":"","category_id":"5","logo":"gamers.jpeg","theme_id":"1"}]};

var forum = json.forum;

for (var i = 0; i < forum.length; i++) {
    var object = forum[i];
    for (property in object) {
        var value = object[property];
        alert(property + "=" + value); // This alerts "id=1", "created=2010-03-19", etc..
    }
}
```

If you want to do this the jQueryish way, grab [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each(json.forum, function(i, object) {
    $.each(object, function(property, value) {
        alert(property + "=" + value);
    });
});
```

I've used the same variable names as the "plain JavaScript" way so that you'll understand better what jQuery does "under the hoods" with it. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok so i have this, but when i run it, it is printing out Undefined within my <li> tag

 
  var url ="forums.json";
  $.getJSON (url, function(data){ 
   alert("data loaded");            
   $.each(data, function(i, item) {                 
    $("#forums").html("<li>"+ item.displayname +"</li>")
    alert("worlds listed");
    });
   });

Comment: Replace `$.each(data, ...` by `$.each(data.forum, ...` exactly as in the example. Your `data` is `json` in my example. JSON is an object. The `forum` is a property which contains the array.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine. Just use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`.

Comment: o yea, but how do i itterate each of the values say i want to get "displayname":"gamers"

and echo what should be gamers

Comment: Your `json` variable will be a JavaScript object. Get it as normal: `for (var user in json.forum) { alert(user.displayname); }`.