# jQuery getJSON Multi Array

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have problem with `getJSON` and a multi-dimensional array. If I use one data:

> { "Id": "1", "Item1": 1, "Item2": "2", "Item3": "3"}

```
$.getJSON(geturl, function(data) {
    $('.Item' + data.Id).html(data.Item1);
}
```

It's working. But if I use a multi array result;

```
[
    { "Id": "1", "Item1": "1", "Item2": "2", "Item3": "3", },
    { "Id": "1", "Item1": "1", "Item2": "2", "Item3": "3", }
]
```

It doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I don't think that the second one is a well formed json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487841/jquery-parse-json-multidimensional-array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487841/jquery-parse-json-multidimensional-array
I try it but how i use Items ? ex: p.Item1 or p.Item2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Your second JSON example is incorrectly formatted as it is missing an opening brace, has commas at the end of arrays and your 'array' value has no key. Try this:

```
[{
    "Array": {
        "Id": "1",
        "Item1": 1,
        "Item2": "2",
        "Item3": "3"
    },
    "Id": "1",
    "Item1": "1",
    "Item2": "2",
    "Item3": "3"
}]
```

You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check the validity of your JSON.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487841/jquery-parse-json-multidimensional-array

Comment: @user1082554 why have you posted that link?

Answer (score 1):

Check your json with http://www.jsonlint.com it is not in correct format.