# JSONArray list another array from result?

Tags: android, json

I need to be able to create a new JSONArray from the one I already have, in the array I have a whole lot of fields called id, another one on each line, how do I get a list of them?

eg. I get this back

```
[{"id":111,"users":"blob"},
 {"id":111,"users":"blob"},
 {"id":111,"users":"blob"},
 {"id":111,"users":"blob"},
 {"id":111,"users":"blob"},
 {"id":111,"users":"blob"}]
```

How would I get a list of just the ID's ?

---

- Edit

Decided to use a for loop straight after this but thanks :D

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); //execute the HttpPost request
JSONArray jsa =  projectResponse(response); //get the json response

for(int i = 0; i < jsa.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jso = jsa.getJSONObject(i);
    publishProgress(jso.getString("id"), jso.getString("name"));
}
```

Comment: what's wrong building a new `JSONArray` with a good 'ol fashioned `for` loop?

Comment: See this post. This will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487841/jquery-parse-json-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
JSONArray yourJSONArray;
List<String> tempIDStringCollection = new List<String>();
...

for(int i = 0; i < yourJSONArray.length(); i++){
        String id = yourJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        tempIDStringCollection.add(id);
}
```

Then to transfer this into another JSONArray, try:

```
JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray(tempIDStringCollection);
```

To skip the `List` creation, try

```
JSONArray yourJSONArray;
JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray();
...

for(int i = 0; i < yourJSONArray.length(); i++){
        String id = yourJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        newArray.put(i, id);
}
```