# How do I parse a JSON multidimensional array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

Here is my JSON which I need to parse:

```
{"opcode":"groupdetails",
 "status":"success",
 "data":[{"Group ID":5,"Group Name":"data structure","Group Subject":"computer science","Role Type":"Teacher"},{"Group ID":4,"Group Name":"information technology","Group Subject":"computer science","Role Type":"Student"},{"Group ID":6,"Group Name":"data mining","Group Subject":"computer science","Role Type":"Parent"},{"Group ID":7,"Group Name":"dccn","Group Subject":"computer science","Role Type":"Teacher"}]}
```

I have tried and implemented the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487841/jquery-parse-json-multidimensional-array) and this is the implementation of JS that was defined in there solution, **which parses only the JSON array**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) 
 {
    var object = data.data[i];
     for (property in object) 
     {
        var value = object[property];
        alert(property + "=" + value);
     }
 }
```

the outer JSON **data** is returned from server and yes I have tried parsing using the following code and there is no result:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{
 var object = data[i];
 for (property in object) 
 {
    var value = object[property];
    alert(property + "=" + value);
 }
}
```

How can I parse the entire JSON using a single method instead of parsing the JSON array separately?

Comment: parse it into what? html, array or ??

Comment: parse into html, further processing is yet to be done
first i need to be sure that parsing is done properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var key in data) {
    if(typeof data[key] === "object") {
        for(var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
            for(var property in data[key][i]) {
                 alert(property + " = " + data[key][i][property]);
            }
        }
    } else if(typeof data[key] === "string") {
        alert(key + " = " + data[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works fine but it shows 0 =[object Object], 1 =[object Object], 2 =[object Object] and 3 =[object Object] for data array

Comment: What is this key will be any field name in the json data?

Comment: Please use proper english and I might answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is a JSON string, you need to decode it to object first. Use `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access each value on my multilevel array:

```
{"dirArray":[{"Dir":{"name":"hr12325","dir_description":"B2B NFIB Field","id":"249"}},{"Dir":{"name":"klk","dir_description":"B2B NFIB klk","id":"251"}}]}
```

using

```
data.dirArray[0].Dir.name
data.dirArray[0].Dir.dir_description
```

as explained [here](http://www.json.org/js.html).