# Looping through JSON multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, json

How can I loop and access each objects. The problem is I cannot access the multidimensional array inside of my `JSON` structure it returns an `[object] [object]`. My `JSON` structure looks like this.

```
{
    "expirationDate": "August 31, 2016",
    "remainingDays": 127,
    "pid": "TE80",
    "seats": [{
        "activeStatus": "Y",
        "pid": "TE80",
        "firstName": "Lenovo X230 Beta SN",
        "guid": "0CA6A94E378F464E9A5EC09102779CFC"
    }]
}
```

Comment: what multidimensional array ?

Comment: Or rather: which language are we talking about?

Comment: if you want to parse this json using jquery then check below link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881429/how-do-i-parse-a-json-multidimensional-array-in-jquery

Comment: im using javascript for in loop in that json object

Comment: the json with the key of seats returns an [object] [object] but im able to access the keys and values of the other data

Comment: Thank you @Rohit Sonaje for the link. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the bracket notation to get the property key that's in an array.

```
seats[0].guid
```

In this particular JSON:

- the `seats` array only has one object
- and that object has 4 key/value pairs
- so in order to get anything, it's always `seats[0]` and the `.key`
- `seats[0].activeStatus`, `seats[0].pid`, `seats[0].firstName`, and `seats[0].guid`

### SNIPPET

```js
var data = 
    '{"expirationDate": "August 31, 2016",'+
    '"remainingDays": 127,'+
    '"pid": "TE80",'+
    '"seats": [{'+
    '"activeStatus": "Y",'+
        '"pid": "TE80",'+
        '"firstName": "Lenovo X230 Beta SN",'+
        '"guid": "0CA6A94E378F464E9A5EC09102779CFC"}]}';


function JSONObj(json) {
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
  return jsonObj;
}

function processLog(result) {
  console.log('Result: ' + result);
}

var status = JSONObj(data).expirationDate;
var GUID = JSONObj(data).seats[0].guid;
var first = JSONObj(data).seats[0].firstName;
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Separate into segments (see script)</li>
  <li>Wrap each segment with single quotes `'`</li>
  <li>Add a `+` after each segment</li>
</ol>

<button onclick="processLog(status);">EXPIRES</button>
<button onclick="processLog(GUID);">GUID</button>
<button onclick="processLog(first);">NAME</button>
```