# How to form a structure of a multidimensional array in json

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to form a structure of a Json where we can put data of a table is form of array. I want each row to be accessed as an array entry. For example.  :

[image]

http://froonystudio.com/table%20layout.png

(users below reputation 10 are not allowed to insert image so could not put my image on my post.)

Code -

```
var ObjSet = {
    "entry1" : .......
}
```

The "entry1" variable should hold the values something like this `array(1)(10) (ie - 1*10 dimension)`.

Thank you.

Comment: You're actually demonstrating an object initializer ("literal") notation, not JSON, except for the quotes around the label `entry1`, which aren't required for object literal labels.

Comment: More on [Using object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) and [Javascript Object Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON).

Comment: Is there a reason why you've used the "jquery" tag? (And as Jared already pointed out, this isn't JSON so the "json" tag doesn't apply either.)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do.

Comment: I am trying to store the data accordingly in json stucture where "id" will also be included in the json data. While displaying the data, data will be accessed only if the "id" matches my search task. Please help me how i can form a json structure and access the data through javascript search using "id" as the search key.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487841/jquery-parse-json-multidimensional-array) will give you what exactly you want.

in JSON , {} represents an object, [] represents an array.
So nesting [] inside a JSON will give you what you want.