# JSON arrays, two properties matching

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I need to parse this JSON data:

```
var myjson = {        
{"groups":[
    {"id":1,"title":"Title1"},
    {"id":2,"title":"Title2"},
    {"id":3,"title":"Title3"}
    ],
        "dials":[
    {"title":"Link1","url":"url1","idgroup":1},
    {"title":"Link2","url":"url2","idgroup":2},
    {"title":"Link3","url":"url3","idgroup":3},
    {"title":"Link4","url":"url4","idgroup":1},
    {"title":"Link5","url":"url5","idgroup":2},
    {"title":"Link6","url":"url6","idgroup":3}
    ]}
};
```

I need to build a bootstrap accordion, with "dials" in "groups" where `dials.idgroup` matches `groups.id`.

No problem to parse the "groups"; to build the accordion markup, I use:

```
$.each(myjson.groups, function (i, group) {
        $grID = group.id;
        $grTitre = group.title;
        $constrAccordion = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#' + $grID + '">' + $grTitre + '</a></h4></div>  <div id="' + $grID + '" class="panel-collapse collapse"><ul class="list-group"></ul></div></div>';
        $('#liens #accordion').append($constrAccordion);
        //  #liens #accordion is my empty markup in my html file.
});
```

But I can't parse dials. I tried with $.grep:

```
makeSpGroup = $.grep(myjson.dials, function (element, index) {
    return element.idgroup === $grID;
});
```

Comment: you can use parseJSON(myjson) may be or see the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487841/jquery-parse-json-multidimensional-array)

Comment: I have already seen this question, it doesn't explain how to match two properties from two different arrays.

Comment: @elektrorl You can see my answer for exact solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with following code;

```
$.each(myjson.groups, function (i, group) {
    var html = '';
    var makeSpGroup = $.grep(myjson.dials, function (element, index) {
        if (element.idgroup == group.id) {
            html += '<li><a href="' + element.url + '">' + element.title + '</a>';
        }
    });

        $grID = group.id;
        $grPosition = group.position;
        $grTitre = group.title;
        $constrAccordion = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#' + $grID + '">' + $grTitre + '</a></h4></div>  <div id="' + $grID + '" class="panel-collapse collapse"><ul class="list-group">' + html + '</ul></div></div>';
        $('#result').append($constrAccordion);
        //  #liens #accordion is my empty markup in my html file.
});
```

Here is a working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/snE8y/1/**

Comment: Wow, thank you! I tried the whole night! It seems so simple now. I tried to use variables, where `if (element.idgroup == group.id)` works.

Comment: Approving my question is appreciable if it works :) You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

See if you can do this:

```
var arr = []; // declare an array outside to be accessible in grep func

$.each(myjson.groups, function (i, group) {
    arr.push(group.id); // add this line
    .......
});
```

then change your grep function little bit this way:

```
makeSpGroup = $.grep(myjson.dials, function (element, index) {
    return $.inArray(arr, element.idgroup); // returns the elem
});
```

#### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58Sn9/)

Comment: Yes, ok, it's an old copy/paste error… not the problem here, but thanks. I edited my question.

Comment: Oh! okay would you plz tell what is it `$grID`? is it declared as an array.

Comment: $grID = group.id; but I don't know if I'm allowed to reuse it in the $.grep function.

Comment: @elektrorl it should not be used this way, although i suggested you an updated answer with a fiddle with little addons of var.

Comment: @elektrorl i have created a demo fiddle for you. you can see the answer i suggested is working.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Jai, but the answer of Hüseyin BABAL (http://jsfiddle.net/snE8y/1/) is perfect! Take a look at it.